# Python Selenium Failed to open file to mark as storage reserve

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-edgedriver

I am using EdgeDriver with Selenium and Python 3

I have been able to fix it by manually creating the `js` folder, but the EdgeDriver window does not load the page, it is showing `Data;,` in the address bar. These may be related on unrelated errors.
But the `scoped_dir13788_764300980` changes when restarting the cmd prompt.

The abridged code is below:

```
# importing required package of webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.opera.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

import schedule
import time
from random import randint


def job():
    while True:
        # Instantiate the webdriver with the executable location of MS Edge
        browser = webdriver.Edge(r"C:\Users\*****\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe")
        sleep(2)
        browser.maximize_window()
        sleep(2)
        browser.get('https://********/) #masked the name of website on purpose
        try:
            # Get the text box to insert Email using selector ID
            myElem_1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'anti-myhub')))
                        
            sleep(3)
            # Entering the email address
            myElem_1.click()
```

The full error is (ip and user names masked):

```
[20444:17192:0308/100926.524:ERROR:storage_reserve.cc(164)] Failed to open file to mark as storage reserve: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir13788_764300980\Default\Code Cache\js

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59454/devtools/browser/416f15a9-5a69-4025-9322-003aa9672acc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 79, in <module>
    job()
  File "check.py", line 21, in job
    browser = webdriver.Edge(r"C:\Users\******\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from tab crashed
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=**.**.**.**)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put in the msedge exe in the rool folder and gave the path as "executable_path = '.\msedgedriver.exe'".